# Convert a batch of csv files to Excel with UTF-8 format

Tags: excel, csv

Convert a batch of csv files to Excel with UTF-8 format without going through each one and do import steps. Now what I do is to create an empty excel file, go to data, from text, select comma separated, and UTF-8 format. I wanna do this for a batch of CSVs.

Thanks, Hanan

Comment: Have a look at my answer here... http://stackoverflow.com/a/32161034/2836621

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel template: import CSV in batch mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26586721/excel-template-import-csv-in-batch-mode)